# Update pending notifications in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift

I have this function below:

```
@objc func decrementBadges(){
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    center.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { (notifications) in
        print("count", notifications.count)
        for notification in notifications{
            //center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: notification.title)
            print(notification.content.badge)
            print(notification.description)
        }
    })
}
```

I am trying to decrement the badge numbers on all the pending notifications. Is this possible? The notification.content.badge is read only and I can't figure out a way to set it.

Comment: all notifications badges? you are talking about just a badge on app icon yes?

Comment: Yes, loop through all the pending notifications and update the badge number that is set when that notification fires.

Answer (score 3):

What you will probably have to do is to cancel the notifications that you want to change and then schedule new ones with the new badge numbers. You can do this by getting the UNNotificationRequest identifiers from each of the notifications in that array you have and then calling 
 `center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [request, identifiers, of, notifications, to, remove])` 
Then schedule the updated notifications. 
The documentation for `UNNotificationRequest.identifier` does say

> If you use the same identifier when scheduling a new notification, the system removes the previously scheduled notification with that identifier and replaces it with the new one.

So you shouldn't *have* to remove them first, but that's up to you.

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up doing. Here's the function I came up with.

Comment: @objc func decrementBadges(eventId: String){
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        
        var arrayOfNotifications: [UNNotificationRequest] = []
        
        center.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { (notifications) in
            print("notifications.count", notifications.count)
            for notification in notifications{

                print(notification.description)
                
                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

Answer (score 1):

```
@objc func decrementBadges(eventId: String){
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    var arrayOfNotifications: [UNNotificationRequest] = []

    center.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { (notifications) in
        print("notifications.count", notifications.count)
        for notification in notifications{

            print(notification.description)

            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

            content.title = notification.content.title
            content.subtitle = notification.content.subtitle
            content.body = notification.content.body
            content.sound = notification.content.sound
            content.userInfo = notification.content.userInfo
            content.categoryIdentifier = notification.content.categoryIdentifier

            if notification.content.badge != nil {
                var int : Int = Int(notification.content.badge!)
                int -= 1
                content.badge = NSNumber(value: int)
            }

            let infoDict = content.userInfo as NSDictionary

            let notificationId:String = infoDict.object(forKey: "IDkey") as! String

            if notificationId != eventId {
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(
                    identifier: notification.identifier,
                    content: content,
                    trigger: notification.trigger
                )

                arrayOfNotifications.append(request)
            }


        }
    })

    self.clearNotifications()

    for notification in arrayOfNotifications {

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(
            notification, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }

}
```